# Generate gif by changing frame's alpha

Tags: gif, animated-gif

I have two png, and want to generate a gif that the png-1’s alpha will decrease step by step and the png-2 will show.

If I generate some new png what different from png-1's alpha, and add them to gif, I can get what I want, but the gif file was very large.

I want to know that is there a way to generate a gif what I want but just have two frames.

Comment: Either you want to "decrease step by step and the png-2 will show" (= large gif file) or you want only two frames (no transition, any "step by step" as you call it = small file). You should make your mind ;)

Comment: No. You cannot have just two frames in such a GIF, for GIF frames themselves cannot be transformed in any way; there is simply no method in the GIF standard to gradually lower the frame transparency. The only way to achieve what you want is to save all intermediate blend states as additional frames — hence the size.